# Python using cStringIO and pisa, ordered list (<ol type="A">) showing numbers not letters

Tags: python, pdf, pisa, cstringio

I'm running a Django website and writing a report that renders a template with view code as an inline PDF file using Pisa and cStringIO. That's all well and good, and working just fine. What I see in HTML from a `render_to_response()` shows up nicely in the PDF format. Now, I have a series of HTML `<ol></ol>` lists. I'd like the outer list to be numeric (`<ol type="1">`) and an inner list to be alphabetic (`<ol type="A">`). I have tried using the inline `type` property of the `<ol>` tag as well as the `list-style-type: upper-alpha`, but neither renders the PDF with the letters for the OL. Instead they are always numbers.

Here's my `render_to_pdf` method:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict, extra_html=None):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    context = Context(context_dict)
    html = template.render(context)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()

    if extra_html:
        html += extra_html

    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(
        StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")),
        dest=result,
        encoding='UTF-8',
        link_callback=fetch_resources
    )

    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')

    return HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))
```

Here's my template:

```
<ol type="1">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>
        3
        <ol type="A">
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>4</li>
</ol>
```

In `render_to_response` it shows:

```
1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
    A. A
    B. B
    C. C
4. 4
```

In `render_to_pdf` it shows:

```
1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
    1. A
    2. B
    3. C
4. 4
```

Is there a way to make some Ordered Lists show the letters?